# Using a Dialog Box in a c++ dll project

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, dialog

I want to add a dialog box to a c++ dll application. First of all I would like to know if this is possible and afterwards how can I do the project compile.

When I set in the configurations "using MFC standard library" I receive the error: fatal error C1189: #error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

When I set the configuration using MFC in a shared dll file I receive the error: general error c101008a: Failed to save the updated manifest to the file ".\Debug\RenameDLL.dll.embed.manifest" false parameter.

Any suggestion how to tackle this? I make also use of windows.h library.

Comment: The second error seems to be a bug. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/329908/mt-exe-general-error-c101008a-failed-to-save-the-updated-manifest-to-the-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definately possible, and "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" is the one you want.

If you have precompiled headers switched on, you'll have a `stdafx.h` in your project which should contain various `#include <afx...>` These are the required MFC headers to include.

Your second error I suspect will go away with a `Rebuild All`.

Another problem you may or may not get is that nothing happens after calling `DoModal()` on your dialog instance. In that case place `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())` before the `DoModal()`

Answer (score 0):

- What is MFC standard library? It should be Standard Windows Library.
- Are you actually using MFC for dialogs (CDialog etc)? If not, don't need to use MFC.
- If you are using MFC, better to create a DLL project supporting MFC, lookup all the settings and put them into your DLL. It includes, C++ settings, linker and **manifest** tool settings.